# Did "Shijou Saikyou Orc-San No Tanoshii Tanetsuke Harem Zukuri" got axed?

Tags: manga-production

I was reading the manga [**Shijou Saikyou Orc-San No Tanoshii Tanetsuke Harem Zukuri**](https://myanimelist.net/manga/125660/Shijou_Saikyou_Orc-san_no_Tanoshii_Isekai_Harem-zukuri) and it was just so good. It has a harem but really serious about that and the MC is quite funny. I am reading the *English scanlated version* and there, the latest chapter was ***Chapter 112 [END]***... but the ending felt quite abrupt.

So the actual question: Did it get axed?

Comment: Precursory research tells that the manga is an adaptation of the light novel, which was last released on June 2021.